# Making sequence of jquery animations a reusable function

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have a bloated function that I pieced together which works mostly how I'd like in a deliberate animation of an expanding div which toggles content and classes. But I don't know how to modify it so that the same function can be reused if there are multiple instances of the same element on the page.

In plain english here's what I'm doing:

- on "click" of .button: // user clicks on expand button
- animate opacity of .intro to 0 // hide intro text from view
- short delay // pause a moment so that animations don't mash together
- animate width of .sidebar to 100% // expand the div horizontally so that it fill full width
- fadeToggle .intro // remove .intro text from page behind the scene
- short delay
- toggleClass "expanded" to .sidebar // this class changes background image of .button
- fadeToggle .full // bring in full content
- animate opacity of .full to 100 // fade full content into view

Then I have another function that reverses these steps and I'm wrapping them all into a function that toggles them. My problem seems to be that it is adding classes to ALL .sidebar elements in the DOM instead of just parent.

```
function sidebarOut(el){
    $('.intro').animate({opacity: "0"}, 50); 
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.sidebar').animate({width: "100%"}, 200); 
        $('.intro').fadeToggle();
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.sidebar').toggleClass('expanded', 50, 'swing');
            },500);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.full').fadeToggle();
            },500);
        $('.full').animate({opacity: "100"}, 100); 
    },300);
}


function sidebarIn(el){
    $('.full').animate({opacity: "0"}, 50); 
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.sidebar').animate({width: "30%"}, 200);
        $('.full').fadeToggle();
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.sidebar').toggleClass('expanded', 50, 'swing');
            },500);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.intro').fadeToggle();
            },500);
        $('.intro').animate({opacity: "100"}, 100); 
    },300);
}


$(".button").click(function() {
  var el = this;
  return (el.t = !el.t) ? sidebarOut(el) : sidebarIn(el);
});
```

Here's the markup:

```
<aside class="sidebar">

    <div class="intro">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In felis enim, rutrum eget sagittis eu, tincidunt finibus felis. Curabitur vehicula risus augue, non viverra justo lacinia ut. Donec ut lobortis erat. </p>
    </div>

    <div class="full">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <h5>Expanded Content Here</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In felis enim, rutrum eget sagittis eu, tincidunt finibus felis. Curabitur vehicula risus augue, non viverra justo lacinia ut. Donec ut lobortis erat. </p>
        <hr>
        <h5>More Content Here</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In felis enim, rutrum eget sagittis eu, tincidunt finibus felis. Curabitur vehicula risus augue, non viverra justo lacinia ut. Donec ut lobortis erat. </p>
    </div>

    <a class="button">Go</a>

</aside>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the provided element to target the correct sidebar by using `$(el).parents('.sidebar')`

Also, I'm not sure what you are doing here:

```
return (el.t = !el.t) ? sidebarOut(el) : sidebarIn(el);
```

since `(el.t = !el.t)` is an assignment operation it will always equate to `true`

You may have intended to do a comparison operation: `(el.t == !el.t)` but that would always return false so again, not a useful condition

Anyway, for your functions something like this should work:

```
function sidebarOut(el){

    var sidebar = $(el).parents('.sidebar');
    var intro = sidebar.find('.intro');
    var full = sidebar.find('.full');

    intro.animate({opacity: "0"}, 50); 

    setTimeout(function(){

        sidebar.animate({width: "100%"}, 200); 

        intro.fadeToggle();
            setTimeout(function(){
                sidebar.toggleClass('expanded', 50, 'swing');
            },500);
            setTimeout(function(){
                full.fadeToggle();
            },500);
        full.animate({opacity: "100"}, 100); 

    },300);
}


function sidebarIn(el){

    var sidebar = $(el).parents('.sidebar');
    var intro = sidebar.find('.intro');
    var full = sidebar.find('.full');

    full.animate({opacity: "0"}, 50); 

    setTimeout(function(){

        sidebar.animate({width: "30%"}, 200);

        full.fadeToggle();
            setTimeout(function(){
                sidebar.toggleClass('expanded', 50, 'swing');
            },500);
            setTimeout(function(){
                intro.fadeToggle();
            },500);
        intro.animate({opacity: "100"}, 100); 
    },300);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jonathan! Here is the example of the part you were confused on: http://jsbin.com/ohOZEYI/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to demo that. I see what's going on there, very interesting!